# Refresh many to many relations on update in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 2 entities with many to many relationship:

Permission (AbstractActiveEntity simply has 2 fields, Long Id and boolean Active):

```java
@Entity(name = "Permission")
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Table(name = "permission")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Permission extends AbstractActiveEntity {

    String code;

    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "permissions",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {MERGE},
            targetEntity = Role.class
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

//equals and hashcode
}
```

and this Role entity:

```java
@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Role extends AbstractActiveEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "roles_permissions",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "permission_id")}
    )
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
//equals and hashcode
}
```

This is my update method:

```java
    public PermissionDto update(@Valid PermissionDto permissionDto) {
        Permission permissionEntity = permissionMapper.toEntity(permissionDto);
        return permissionMapper.toDto(permissionRepository.save(permissionEntity));
    }
```

Update API:

```java
    @PatchMapping
    public PermissionDto update(@RequestBody @Valid PermissionDto permissionDto) {
        return permissionService.update(permissionDto);
    }
```

PermissionDto:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PermissionDto extends AbstractActiveDto {

    @NotBlank
    private String code;

    private Set<Long> rolesIds = new HashSet<>();

}
```

RoleDto:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)
@Data
public class RoleDto extends AbstractActiveDto {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Long> permissionsIds;

}
```

PermissionMapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN,
        builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true),
        uses = RoleMapper.class)
public interface PermissionMapper extends EntityMapper<Permission, PermissionDto> {

    @Override
    @Mapping(source = "rolesIds", target = "roles")
    Permission toEntity(PermissionDto dto);

    @Override
    @Mapping(source = "roles", target = "rolesIds")
    PermissionDto toDto(Permission entity);

    @AfterMapping
    default void assignPermissionToRoles(@MappingTarget Permission permission) {
        var permissionIdSet = new HashSet<Permission>();
        permissionIdSet.add(permission);
        permission.getRoles().forEach(role -> role.setPermissions(permissionIdSet));
    }

}
```

RoleMapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN,
        uses = PermissionMapper.class)
public abstract class RoleMapper {

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public abstract Role toEntity(RoleDto dto);

    public abstract RoleDto toDto(Role entity);

    Set<Role> mapRolesIdsToRoles(Set<Long> rolesIds) {
        return rolesIds.stream()
                       .map(roleId -> roleRepository.findById(roleId).orElseThrow(
                               () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Role with ID %d not found".formatted(roleId))
                       ))
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    Set<Long> mapRolesToRolesIds(Set<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(Role::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

}
```

When I try to update an existing permission that has a role related to it, hibernate does not delete the current relation and insert the new one, it only inserts the new one.

for example, if I have a permission related to Role with id 1, and I try to update it by passing this JSON:

```json
{
  "id": 15991,
  "active": true,
  "code": "NEW_ROLE",
  "rolesIds": [
     2
  ]
}
```

Then I end up with 2 rows in the join table, one for roleId 1 and another for roleId 2.

What I'd like to happen is to have the role relations refreshed on each update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relations are not symmetric. If you change:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "roles_permissions",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "permission_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}
)
@ToString.Exclude
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

And:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "roles_permissions",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "permission_id")}
)
@ToString.Exclude
private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
```

Then the update will propagade correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So what happened when you tried to save `permissionEntity` (without fetching its reference) is Hibernate generated several queries:

1. Select by id(`15991`) query to check wether insert or update -> Existed!
2. Update all columns of `permissionEntity`
3. There is only 1 item in `Set<Role> roles` and this is a new object reference -> Insert to relation table.

To solve this, let's update your service by fetching entity instead of mapping them from dto.

```
Permission permissionEntity = permissionRepository.findOne(permissionDto.getId());
// Update properties by mapper

Set<Role> roles = roleRepository.findByIdIn(permissionDto.getRoleIds());
permissionEntity.getRoles().clear();
permissionEntity.getRoles().addAll(roles);
permissionRepository.save(permissionEntity)
```

You can refer to this [doc](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate).

Comment: This did not work for some reason